# Ambiguity in Java interface variable

Tags: java, ambiguity

Consider I have two interfaces having same variable names and also this variable name is same as one of the two interfaces name.
Eg.,

```
interface Parent1{  
  public static final String Parent1= "VALUE1";  // Variable Parent1 is same as interface name 
}  
interface Parent2{  
  public static final String Parent1= "VALUE2";  
}
```

Say if i have a class that implements the above two interfaces and if i need to access the variable Parent1 in interface Parent1, how can i access.
Eg.,

```
class Child implements Parent1, Parent2{
  void myCode(){
    System.out.println(Parent1.Parent1); // Does not compile. Because Parent1(before dot) is considered as variable
    System.out.println(Parent2.Parent1); // Does compile
  }
}
```

I know the variable names does not follow standard. But wanted to understand how java overcomes this ambiguity.

Edit:
People says it is working(in comments). But when I executed it says

```
/Child.java:9: error: reference to Parent1 is ambiguous
        System.out.println(Parent1.Parent1); // Does not compile. Because Parent1(before dot) is considered as variable
                           ^
  both variable Parent1 in Parent1 and variable Parent1 in Parent2 match
/Child.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(Parent1.Parent1); // Does not compile. Because Parent1(before dot) is considered as variable
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable Parent1
  location: variable Parent1 of type String
2 errors
```

Comment: Compiles fine for me.

Comment: it is working where u face issue. It is working

Comment: Which version of Java are you using and which compiler?  Also ... which one are >>you<< using @JoeC?

Comment: I'm using JDK 1.8.0_66. Also it is from https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler

Comment: compilation is failing.

Comment: please read about Java Heap,Method area, I think you will get the mistake that you have done here :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to let you know that how java overcome this ambiguity on 'Paret1' variable while you are calling with Parent1 reference.

Java will get exact address While you are calling Parent2.Parent1. 
But due to Parent1,Parent2 interfaces implementation the property 'Parent1' is considered as an ambiguous property. 
Since these are static variables which are saved inside method area inside JVM.

So still if you want to access that variable value you have to give exact reference to compiler. for that you can use reflection. as below,

```
 try {
        Class parent = Class.forName("yourpackage.Parent1");
        Field field = parent.getDeclaredField("Parent1");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(parent);
        System.out.println(value); // this will print out the 'Parent1' value

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This just looks like you are using Parent1 independently. How to use inside Child class- is not solving this problem. To use it independently, you dont need reflection, you can simply invoke as  Parent1.Parent1!